# 10-teeth/9-teeth Sprocket Efficiency Losses

Tags: cassette, sprocket

Almost each time 10T (or 9T) sprockets on cassettes are mentioned, there are remarks about efficiency losses when such sprockets are used. But I haven't found quantified information about these claims.

The only reference I found so far is this [article from SRAM](https://www.sram.com/en/life/stories/10-tooth-cogs-for-the-win), where they actually do actually aknowledge that 10T sprockets are less efficient, but they mention that it's incorrect to only look at this aspects: modern drivetrains are designed as a whole and that they actually have other ways to limit these efficiency losses: chain design, larger jockey wheels, teeth shape and thickness, and chainring design all impact efficiency. Looking at the big picture, at 44kph on flat, for a rider producing 400W, drivetrain losses represent only 5% of the total losses (the rest being shared between aero 86% and rolling resitance 9%). Using a 10T sprocket is according to them 1% less efficient than a 11T on, but that would represent about 0.05% of the total, which I would qualify as negligible (but I'm not a pro racer)

Are there other studies (and probably less biaised) that study theses losses? Even if SRAM is wrong by a 20 factor, it would be still quite negligible for non-competitive uses.

[EDIT] To be more specific, the comparison that would interest me would be about systems with comparable ratios and similar architecture. For example, in MTBs a 1x 32/10 combination on a M6100/M7100/M8100 vs a 1x 36/11 on a previous generation, as you rarely just change the smallest sprocket, but the whole system.

Comment: Care needs to be taken with this level is difference. As part of a system, the savings might be offset by other things, aerodynamics, weight, and even rider profile - maybe the less efficient 10 puts the rider in a more optimal cadence more often, increasing efficiency of the system (or not).

Comment: I believe there is a whole lot in the engineering world about the topic of efficiency losses of roller chains over different radius pulleys

Comment: @mattnz it might be worth a new question, but the research I’ve seen points to the direction that the optimal cadence doesn’t really exist but the efficiency and max power curves are quite flat.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of curious why is it so important that larger sprockets would not improve efficiency. We're already taking the benefits of carbon fiber everywhere, aero frames or even larger derailleur pulleys for granted and larger sprockets are quite a low hanging fruit compared to those.

Comment: Is efficiency the main reason for not using smaller cogs? I could also imagine that there are some mechanical issues, such as too much stress on a small number of teeth causing increased wear or even failure. Or chain skipping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Looking at the big picture, at 44kph on flat, for a rider producing 400W, drivetrain losses represent only 5% of the total losses (the rest being shared between aero 86% and rolling resitance 9%). Using a 10T sprocket is according to them 1% less efficient than a 11T on, but that would represent about 0.05% of the total, which I would qualify as negligible (but I'm not a pro racer)

As shown by the link in Ted's answer, the jump from an 11T to a 10T isn't that great an efficiency loss (approximately 1W).  However the chart also shows there is a large difference in how the final gear ratio is achieved.  By using a larger chain ring and larger sprocket (53/11 vs 48/10) gives a saving of 6-7W which is quite a large figure.

Given that the losses in both drivetrains increase in a straight line in the lower half of the cassette, we can extrapolate that a 9t would likely cost an extra 1-2W vs a 10T.

As to how important these losses are?  Well I guess that's somewhat down to an individual to decide, but I can attempt to give some context.

**For a pro:**
A pro produces more power than was used in the test and is more likely to spend more of their time in the smaller sprockets.  At 400W we could guesstimate losses in the region of 8-10W using 48/10 vs 53/11.  Given that pro teams will spend $$$$ on special fabrics and ceramic bearings to find this level of power savings we can see that it is significant to them.  It's the difference between winning races and not.

**For an amateur/enthusiast:**
The 250W the test was performed at is in the region of the FTP of a typical fit amateur rider.  The 6-7W loss is significant, a rider in this category would be quite happy to gain that much power from 8 weeks training, so to then 'lose' it by choice of drivetrain is certainly not desirable.

However despite what they may claim, realistically, this type of rider doesn't spend that much time in the 12,11,10t sprockets, they simply aren't strong enough.

Speaking for myself, I just bought a bike with a 48/10 top gear fully aware of the slightly increased losses.  I expect to spend most of my time in gears 48-21 to 48-15 where the losses are much smaller.

**For a recreational rider:**
A recreational rider probably only produces half the power the test was performed at and therefore the losses will be smaller (we could guesstimate ~4-5W).  A recreational rider probably has no idea what a Watt is and doesn't care either.  They may however like their ride to be easier.  Due to the nature of aerodynamic drag, the drivetrain losses are a much bigger percentage of the total losses for a recreational rider.  An extra 5W could make a ride noticeably faster/easier for them.

However the bike industry is very reluctant to make gearing for recreational riders.  With typically sized chainrings, a recreational rider will rarely be in the lower half of the cassette and are more likely to be found struggling over geared.  So basically the comparative losses found in the lower half of the cassette become irrelevant.

Comment: Don’t focus too much on the 12, 11, 10t sprockets, most people use them rarely and for a short time only (to keep pedaling a tiny bit longer or more efficiently on those 65km/h descents). However, (at least according to the VeloNews article) efficiency already starts to drop quite noticeable around 16t which is a sprocket size you’ll be using much more often and longer.

Comment: @Michael yes, I agree.  But the velo news article also exaggerates the issue slightly for the typical amateur rider.  Very few are running 53t outers any more - a more typical subcompact (52) or compact (50) will reduce the difference.  I could certainly see a compelling argument for using the new Shimano 54 outers with a modified cassette using a 12t smallest cog.

Comment: @Michael For MTB usage, the 12-11-10 come into play more often, considering the tiny chainrings used nowadays.

Comment: “Due to the nature of aerodynamic drag, the drivetrain losses are a much bigger percentage of the total losses for a recreational rider.” – I don't think that's true. The proper calculation is: aero + rolling resistance is the _required output power_ from the drivetrain; the drivetrain adds some percentage on top of that power. If you put less power into overcoming aero resistance, less power goes through the drivetrain and the losses there scale down as well. (In practice it's true anyway that recreational riders have more losses in their drivetrain, but that's mostly due to maintenance.)

Answer (score 6):

Studies, yes there are.  Here are a couple of VeloNews links that give some unbiased information.

[Technical FAQ - Calculating drivetrain friction losses](https://www.velonews.com/gear/technical-faq-calculating-drivetrain-friction-losses/)

This link is one of Lennard Zinn's installments of his Technical FAQ series. In this installment, the majority of it addresses some details of smaller vs bigger cogs and how the friction in the chain is affected in each.  In one example he compares the difference in estimated losses between a 52x26 gear setup and a 26x13 gear setup (identical ratios).  His estimate had the smaller gear setup (26x13) having higher losses by about 30 percent.

[Gear Issue - Friction differences between 1X and 2X drivetrains](https://www.velonews.com/gear/gear-issue-friction-differences-between-1x-and-2x-drivetrains/)

Now THIS link (circa May 2019?) gets into actual measured data. There is a lot of intriguing stuff here for a data junkie, but to the gist of your initial question, focus on the final paragraph, where they discuss what they would expect from the "new" SRAM 10-tooth cog based on the testing they just performed in the article.

"*Smith said the AXS’s 10-tooth cog would likely increase friction in the drivetrain, as would the smaller chainrings. SRAM’s new narrow Flattop chain could also impact losses due to friction. However, we simply do not know what the final friction losses are—we will have to wait for our next trip into the lab.*"

I have yet to see that trip to the lab, but hopefully we will soon.

And I would agree, SRAM would definitely be biased in the way they present their product (and who would blame them, that is Marketing 101).